# Going to a specific line number using Less in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, search, less-unix

I have a file that has around million lines. I need to go to line number 320123 to check the data. How do I do that?

Comment: What about doing that with `more`? :-)

Comment: because: [`less` is more, but more `more` than `more` is, so `more` is less `less`, so use more `less` if you want less `more`.](https://www.slackbook.org/html/file-commands-pagers.html)

Answer (score 671, accepted):

With `n` being the line number:

- `ng`: Jump to line number n. Default is the start of the file.
- `nG`: Jump to line number n. Default is the end of the file.

So to go to line number 320123, you would type `320123g`.

Copy-pasted straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

Comment: ... and don't hit enter after `g`, or you will jump one further line.

Comment: This nor the other answers work for [the BusyBox version of less](https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/Property:less): `less 9581553g -N file.txt         
less: can't open '9581553g': No such file or directory` and also: `less +G -N file.txt 
less: can't open '+G': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Wimateeka you should enter these commands being in `less` not in shell. First you open the file `less file.txt` and then enter your command `9581553g`

Comment: That makes so much more sense. I was treating it like `sed` or `awk` where you could give specific line numbers as parameters. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: if its a large file, it may take some time to seek to the position....be patient

Answer (score 281):

To open at a specific line straight from the command line, use:

```
less +320123 filename
```

If you want to see the line numbers too:

```
less +320123 -N filename
```

You can also choose to display a specific line of the file at a specific line of the terminal, for when you need a few lines of context. For example, this will open the file with line 320123 on the 10th line of the terminal:

```
less +320123 -j 10 filename
```

Answer (score 68):

You can use `sed` for this too -

```
sed -n '320123'p filename
```

This will print line number **320123**.

If you want a range then you can do -

```
sed -n '320123,320150'p filename
```

If you want from a particular line to the very end then -

```
sed -n '320123,$'p filename
```

Answer (score 47):

From within less (in Linux):

```
 g and the line number to go forward

 G and the line number to go backwards
```

Used alone, g and G will take you to the first and last line in a file respectively; used with a number they are both equivalent.

An example; you want to go to line 320123 of a file,

> press 'g' and after the colon type in the number 320123

Additionally you can type '-N' inside less to activate / deactivate the line numbers. You can as a matter of fact pass any command line switches from inside the program, such as -j or -N.

NOTE: You can provide the line number in the command line to start less (less +number -N) which will be much faster than doing it from inside the program:

```
less +12345 -N /var/log/hugelogfile
```

This will open a file displaying the line numbers and starting at line 12345

*Source: man 1 less and built-in help in less (less 418)*

Comment: interestingly, google decided to take parts of your answer for their displayed answer when googling: "less go to line" (a good answer imo)

Answer (score 5):

For editing this is possible in `nano` via `+n` from command line, e.g.,

`nano +16 file.txt`

To open `file.txt` to line 16.

Comment: adding -c to the nano command is also useful - doing so will cause nano to always show the current line number while editing

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents, in long files it is quicker to move to a given percentage, e.g typing `40%` moves to the `40-th` percentile of the length.